# React Redux Fetching Data From Api is Null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using react and redux to fetch data from an api, but when I try to retrieve the data in my view, I get an error :

> TypeError: catData is undefined

I am having a hard time retrieving data from my api in my view, despite the fact that everything is fine on the backened. Any advise on what im doing wrong/ recommendations on how to retrieve data from the reducer will be highly appreciated.

My view looks like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect} from "react-redux";

// @material-ui/core components
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner'
import { fetchCategories } from "../../../actions/data"


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        catData: state.categories

    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchCategories: () => dispatch(fetchCategories())
    }
}


function CategoriesSection({ catData,fetchCategories}) {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCategories();
    }, []);    

  return catData.loading ? (

    <div xs={12} sm={10} md={10} lg={10} style={{marginTop: 10}} > 
        <Loader
            type="Puff"
            color="red"
            height={200}
            width={200}
            style={{ display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center" }}
        />
    </div> 
    
    ) 
    
    : catData.error ? (
        <h2> {catData.error} </h2>
    ): (
        <div>

            <div className={classes.title} justify="center">
                    <h2 className={classes.title}>Our Categories</h2>
            </div>

            <div>
                {
                    catData && catData.cat
                }
            </div>

        </div>

    )
 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoriesSection)
```

My reducer looks like this :

```
import {
    
    CATEGORIES_FETCH_REQUEST,
    CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    CATEGORIES_FAIL
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    categories: [],
    businesses: [],
    error: ''
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {

        case CATEGORIES_FETCH_REQUEST: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };

        case CATEGORIES_SUCCESS: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                categories: action.payload
            };    

        case CATEGORIES_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                categories: null,
                error: action.payload
            };    

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And my actions looks like this :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
    CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    CATEGORIES_FAIL,
    CATEGORIES_FETCH_REQUEST,
} from "./types";

export const fetchCategories = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchCategoryRequest)

        axios.get('https://api.xxxxxxx.com/api/v1/categories/')
        .then(response => {
            const categories = response.data
            dispatch(fetchCategorySuccess(categories))
        })
        .catch(error => {
            const err = error.message
            dispatch(fetchCategoryFailure(err))
        })
    }
}

const fetchCategoryRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: CATEGORIES_FETCH_REQUEST
    }
}

const fetchCategorySuccess = categories => {
    return {
        type: CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
        payload: categories
    }
}

const fetchCategoryFailure = err => {
    return {
        type: CATEGORIES_FAIL,
        payload: err
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you create your store, combine your reducers? It appears you've possibly also some mismatch in the mapped props. You map `state.categories` to `catData`, and then try to access `catData.loading` and `catData.error` in the UI code. I guess `state.categories` is *that* specific slice of state.

Comment: @DrewReese the problem was in my reducer, mismatched props

Comment: Is this resolved or do you still have an issue?

Comment: @DrewReese, it is resolved